# VHDL code and unintended latches

Tags: fpga, vhdl, state-machines, register

I am working on coding a Regsiter `a1` with input signals `b1,rst` and `wra1`
the register `a1` is initialized to a specific value at reset.
`a1` only changes its value to `b1` when `wra1` is `1` else it keeps the old value

```
process(clk,regrst)
begin
    if(regrst='1')then  
        a1 <= (others =>'0');
    elsif(clk'event and clk='1') then       
        if(wra1='1')then
            a1 <= b1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

In this statement I have written the register process to update on the needed wra1 signal but I am confused on how to make it keep the old value of the output in case this write signal is 0
does this concept generate unintended latches to store the previous value? if so what can I add as a default register assignment in the begning of the process ? and should I include the else statement with

```
a1<=a1;
```

Thank you

Comment: Your code generates a register with asynchronous reset and write enable as intended. A else statement is not needed. This works because your sensitivity list has only asynchronous signals listed (the clock and reset signal). Unless there is a rising edge, there can't be any changes except for reset. So this is a true flip flop behavior, not a latch behavior :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paebbels mentions in his comment, your process works exactly as you intend it.

You get a flip-flop, and not a latch, because of the condition on `clk` in your if statement, which specifies that `a1` is assigned only when clk rises. `clk'event` means a change just happened on `clk`, so `clk'event and clk='1'` means "`clk` just changed and is now one", i.e. a rising edge.

A default assignment as the one you propose is not necessary because a signal keeps its previous value if one is not assigned explicitly. This simplifies sequential processes as the one you posted, but is also the source of unwanted latches in combinatorial processes.

The following is a latch:

```
process(wra1, b1) begin
    if(wra1='1')then
        a1 <= b1;
    end if;
end process;
```

Note that 1) this process has no clock (i.e. no rising edge condition on a signal), just like a process describing combinatorial logic, but 2) no value is assigned to `a1` when `wra1` is not 1, which means it keep its current value until `wra1` is 1 again, even if `b1` changes. That's the semantic of a latch.